# spread operator in react throwing error of Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here is the code where I have included spread operator

```
style={{ ...styles.detailsRow.icon, alignSelf: 'centre' }}
```

What things do I need to install or add to make it run?

And also what is its equivalent in `es2015`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to configure Babel to use the transform-object-rest-spread plugin.
Refer to the following link for details: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

Comment: What specifically did you run? This package doesn't involve eslint, seems like that's an unrelated exist issue with your project

Comment: i had installed eslint before, so I deleted it and installed transform-object-rest-spread again. I followed all the methods given in the link but it is still giving me that error. Do you know of es2015 equivalent of the code?

Comment: There is the eslint-config-keystone package mentioned in the error messages you posted before. This package requires the outdated eslint version. Try removing the eslint-config-keystone dependency and installing babel plugin again.

Comment: You could also use babel-preset-stage-0, and add this to your .babelrc

```"presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]```

Just run `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0`

Comment: I did the above steps still getting same error "Unexpected token this"

Answer (score 14):

You are missing one babel preset, stage-0

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```

if you have `.bablerc` file add following to it.

```
{
  "presets":[
    "es2015", "react", "stage-0"
  ]
}
```

Or added to webpack config in loader.

Comment: Anyone stumbling upon this issue should know that babel presets are no longer supported. https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/07/27/removing-babels-stage-presets

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and the fix I found was to add `experimentalObjectRestSpread` to the `ecmaFeatures` setting in `.eslintrc`:

```
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 6,
  "sourceType": "module",
  "ecmaFeatures": {
     "jsx": true,
     "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
  }
}
```