# react js compile error in line with 3 dot

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am learning React js+ Redux, I create a todo app which is followed:

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html page's instruction.

After I run webpack, getting error:

> ERROR in
>   ./jsx/reducers/todos.jsx Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token (15:8)

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you check this http://stefan.magnuson.co/articles/frontend/using-es7-spread-operator-with-webpack/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browserify, Babel 6, Gulp - Unexpected token on spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745118/browserify-babel-6-gulp-unexpected-token-on-spread-operator)

Comment: @Panther, thanks, after install babel-preset-stage-2, and add stage-2, it is working now

Answer (score 5):

FYI, there's another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44928843/4073549) open for that same issue.

Did you install the [babel-preset-stage-0](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-0.html) ?

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```

Then you need to update your webpack.config.js by addind *stage-0* to the presets:

```
presets: ['env','react','stage-0']
```

By the way, I'm learning *redux* too and I found this series of [videos](https://youtu.be/ucd5x3Ka3gw) to make the concept of redux very simple and clear.

PS: I see you already found a solution in the comments of your post. FYI, stage-0 includes stage-2.