# Showing error while using the spread operator ..this.state in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I wrote validation for my login page. While I execute my script my getting error at `...this.state`. Below I'm attaching my code.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a63D6.png)

```js
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import '../css/onboarding.scss';
class Login extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    state = {
      email: "",
      emailError: "",
      password: "",
      passwordError: ""
     }
     this.change = this.change.bind(this);
  };
   change(e) {
   this.props.onChange({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
   this.setState({
     [e.target.name]: e.target.value
   });
 };
 validate() {
     let isError = false;
     const errors = {
       emailError: "",
       passwordError: ""
     };
     if (this.state.password.length < 5) {
      isError = true;
      errors.usernameError = "password needs to be atleast 5 characters long";
    }

    if (this.state.email.indexOf("@") === -1) {
      isError = true;
      errors.emailError = "Requires valid email";
    }

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      ...errors
    });

    return isError;
  };
  onSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
    const err = this.validate();
    if (!err) {
      // clear form
      this.setState({
        email: "",
        emailError: "",
        password: "",
        passwordError: ""
      });
      this.props.onChange({
        email:    "",
        password: ""
      });
    }
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <main className="aw-login-wrapper">
        <article className="aw-aside-panel aw-banner-aside">
            <section className="aw-slider-list">
               <div className="aw-slider-item aw-slider-image-1 active">
                    <div className="aw-slider-content">
                        <h3>Work is what you do,</h3>
                        <h3>not where you do it</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="aw-slider-item aw-slider-image-2">
                    <div className="aw-slider-content">
                        <h3>Live locally,</h3>
                        <h3>work globally</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="aw-slider-item aw-slider-image-3">
                    <div className="aw-slider-content">
                        <h3>To think outside the box,</h3>
                        <h3>go outside the box</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="aw-slider-item aw-slider-image-4">
                    <div className="aw-slider-content">
                        <h3>Go virtually anywhere,</h3>
                        <h3>no CO required</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul className="aw-slider-navigation">
                    <li className="slider-active"></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </article>
        <article className="aw-account-column-right">
           <a className="aw-brand-logo"></a>
            <section className="aw-account-panel aw-login-panel" id="signin-form-container">
                <div className="aw-account-third-parties">
                    <h3>Sign in to your account</h3>
                    <div className="aw-btn-col-wrapper">
                        <button className="aw-btn aw-btn-google" id="signin-with-google">Sign in with Google</button>

                        <div className="aw-hor-divider"><span>or</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <fieldset className="aw-account-fieldset" id="signin-input-group">
                    <div className="aw-form-group">
                        <label>Email address</label>
                       <input type="text" className="aw-input-default email-input" name = "email" id="user-email" tabIndex="1"
                       value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={e => this.change(e).bind(this)} />
                        <p className="aw-error-txt"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="aw-form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" className="aw-input-default" id="user-password" name = "password" tabIndex= "2"
                        value={this.state.password}
                        onChange={e => this.change(e).bind(this)} />
                        <p className="aw-error-txt"></p>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" className="uncheck" id="remember-me" tabIndex="3" style={{visibility: 'hidden'}}/>
                    <span className="aw-label-checkbox" style={{visibility:'hidden'}}>Remember me</span>
                    <span className="aw-label-forget-pass" id="process-forgot-password">Forgot your password?</span>
                    <p className="aw-error-txt" id="error-message"></p>
                    <button  className="aw-btn aw-btn-secondary" id="process-login" tabIndex= "3">Login</button>
                </fieldset>
                <p className="aw-account-footer-txt">Don't have an account? <Link to="signup" id="signupHtml" tabIndex="4">Sign up</Link></p>
            </section>
            <section className="aw-password-reset-success aw-message-center">
                <h3 className="aw-form-header">Password reset sent</h3>
                <p className="aw-form-paragraph">We've just emailed you instructions on how to reset your password.</p>
                <a href="">Back to Login</a>
            </section>
            <p className="aw-error-txt" id="expired-mail-link">The link got expired, please try again.</p>
            <section className="aw-account-panel aw-message-center aw-forget-panel">
               <h3 className="aw-form-header">Forgot your password?</h3>
               <p className="aw-form-paragraph">We'll email you instructions on how to reset it.</p>
                <fieldset className="aw-account-fieldset">
                    <div className="aw-form-group">
                        <label>Email address</label>
                        <input type="text" className="aw-input-default" name = "email" id="mail-reset-password" tabIndex= "1"/>
                        <p className="aw-error-txt" id="resent-pwd-mail">Email is not registered with Anywhereworks. </p>
                    </div>
                    <button className="aw-btn aw-btn-secondary" id="resetPassword" tabIndex="2">Reset password</button>
                </fieldset>
                <p className="aw-account-footer-txt">Remembered it? <Link to="login" tabIndex="3">Login</Link></p>
            </section>
        </article>
    </main>
    )
  }
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: could you paste the error itself?

Comment: yes sure. I added an image. Once check.

Comment: Maybe not related, but is this valid syntax `import '../css/onboarding.scss';`?
 Don't you have to give a name to the import or something?

Comment: You should try `this.setState({...errors});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spread operator in react throwing error of Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490804/spread-operator-in-react-throwing-error-of-unexpected-token)

Comment: @NafiulIslam Why? The problem is with the spread operator, your suggestion will fail all the same. satya, see the duplicate link.