# Can't get the array state value in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, webpack

When I try to get value `...this.state.users` shows error in react

React Code

```
handleChange(i, e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        let users = [...this.state.users];
        users[i] = { ...users[i], [name]: value };
        this.setState({ users });
    }
```

My webpack file

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = (env) => {
    const isProduction = env === 'production';
    return {
        entry: './src/index.js',
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
            filename: 'bundle.js',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
                },
            ],
        },
    };
}
```

And the error is

```
 ERROR in ./src/components/Index.js
[1] Module build failed: SyntaxError: E:/Program/reactjs/check/client/src/components/Index.js: Unexpected token (47:15)
```

Please help me to fix this error

Comment: You sure `this.state.users` is spreadable? Maybe check if its an object or array before spreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to configure babel correctly.
According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490804/spread-operator-in-react-throwing-error-of-unexpected-token/44928843#44928843), you need to make sure that you have the stage-0 preset installed:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```

and configured:

```
{
  "presets":[
    "es2015", "react", "stage-0"
  ]
}
```

However, if you are using Babel v7 or higher you have to use a [different installation & configuration](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread):

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
```

and put it into your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```