# Object property become undefined after call setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm new at React js, i want to ask, i have a object, i want to update some property from the object, but when i change one property from the object, another property is update too and the value is undefined
i try to using spread operator but when i running, it show error not defined. This is my code

```
export default class Message extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        isLoggedIn: SystemStore.isLoggedIn(),
        profile: ProfileStore.getProfile(),
        messageInfo: {
          fullName: SystemStore.systemUser().fullName,
          site: '',
          email: '',
          phone: '',
        },
        subject: '',
        description: '',
        type: '',
        errorMessage: '',
        errorDialog: '',
        isSubmited: false,
        successMessage: '',
        submitting: false
      };
....
  clearForm(){
    this.setState({
      messageInfo: {
        ...messageInfo, //in here i get error messageInfo is not defined
          subject: '',
          description: ''//if doing this i get error SyntaxError
      }})
  }


  handleProfileChange(){
    this.setState({
      messageInfo: {
        ....messageInfo, site: ProfileStore.getProfile().primarySite.name,
      }});
    console.log(this.state.messageInfo.fullName);
    console.log(this.state.messageInfo.site);
  }

  handleSubjectChange(evt){
    this.setState({ subject: evt.target.value }, () => {
      if(this.state.messageInfo.subject === 'PRAYER') {
        this.setState({ type: 'REQUEST' });
      } else if(this.state.messageInfo.subject === 'ADDRESS') {
        this.setState({ type: 'INFORMATION' });
      } else if(this.state.messageInfo.subject === 'VISIT'){
        this.setState({ type: 'REQUEST' });
      }
    });
  }
    
  handleMessageChange(evt){
    this.setState(prevState=>({
      messageInfo: {
        ...prevState.messageInfo, description: evt.target.value
      }}));
  }
```

Any suggestion where i got wrong? Thank you

Comment: @CertainPerformance, the code has trimmed, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your state has multiple properties. If you start out with properties `messageInfo` and `type`, for example, and then you do `this.setState({ messageInfo: newMessageInfo })`, then the new state will have *only* the `messageInfo` property; the `type` property will have been lost, because its value wasn't passed to `setState`.

Instead, spread the previous state into the calls of `setState` before defining the new property:

```
clearForm(){
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    messageInfo: {
      ...this.state.messageInfo,
      // ...
```

and

```
handleSubjectChange(evt){
  this.setState({ ...this.state, subject: evt.target.value }, () => {
```

and so on.

Comment: so in the clearForm function there is two setState?

Comment: There's only one `setState` in it, but you need to spread the previous `messageInfo` state into the new `messageInfo` property. It's not a standalone variable, it's a property of the state, so you have to reference the state to get to it: `...this.state.messageInfo`

Comment: Hmm, it still show SyntaxError: UnexpectedToken at  `...this.state, messageInfo:{..`

Comment: Sounds like either you typed the syntax incorrectly, or your environment isn't configured to understand spread syntax

Comment: for the environment configuration i don't know exactly, but it possible if my environment not configured to understand spread syntax

Comment: Try: `const obj = {}; const obj2 = { ...obj }` That'll tell you whether the issue is with your environment or with this particular script

Comment: where i suppossed to put `const obj = {}; const obj2 = { ...obj }`?

Comment: Anywhere. At the top of your script would work - just type it in to see if the syntax is recognized.

Comment: where `const obj2` called? Because it gets `obj2 was defined but never used`

Comment: That's a linter warning, not a runtime error. Just ignore the linter and see if the syntax is recognized. If you have to pass the linter to run the script, then just reference the variable somewhere, it doesn't matter where or how - just find out if spread syntax is supported.

Comment: Ok i tried and show the error SyntaxError: UnexpectedToken at `const obj = {} and const obj2 = { ...obj }` while parsing file

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38490804, it sounds like you're using an old version of Babel.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly access `messageInfo`. There are two ways to fetch it:

```
clearForm(){
    this.setState({
      messageInfo: {
        ...this.state.messageInfo,
          subject: '',
          description: ''
      }
    })
  }
```

or

```
clearForm(){
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      messageInfo: {
        ...prevState.messageInfo,
        subject: '',
        description: ''
      }
   })
  }
```

Comment: i had tried it but its still show SyntaxError Unexpected Token at ...this.state.messageInfo or ...prevState.messageInfo

Answer (score 0):

In clearForm(){} function you cannot use messageInfo  directly, you should define is a state type not variable.

```
        clearForm(){
         this.setState({
          messageInfo: {
           ...this.state.messageInfo, 
              subject: '',
              description: ''
           }})
        }
```

Comment: i had tried it but still showing SyntaxError: Unexpected Token at `...this.state.messageInfo`

Comment: your constructor is not close with } please check this

Comment: It was close correctly, hosently i just trimmed my code, and this `}` is trimmed